# xcodebuild generating empty compile_commands.json

Tags: iphone, xcode5, code-analysis, xctool, oclint

I am using following commands to use the oclint with xcode 5-

Step1: xcodebuild -target OClintDemo -configuration Debug -scheme OClintDemo -sdk iphonesimulator
Step2: OClintDemo jenkins$ xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator | tee xcodebuild.log
Step3: oclint-xcodebuild xcodebuild.log
Step4: oclint-json-compilation-database -- -o=report.html

but i am getting compile_commands.json empty file, and report.html contains following-
OCLint Report Summary: TotalFiles=0 FilesWithViolations=0 P1=0 P2=0 P3=0 [OCLint (http://oclint.org) v0.7]

Answer (score 6):

Xcode 8 does not support xctool, you can use [xcpretty](https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty). Your xcodebuild command should be like this

If you are using a workspace

```
xcodebuild -workspace WORKSPACE_NAME.xcworkspace -scheme SELECTED_SCHEME | xcpretty -r json-compilation-database --output compile_commands.json
```

For a single project

```
xcodebuild -project PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj | xcpretty -r json-compilation-database --output compile_commands.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the question was asked at the time xcode 5

Answer (score 6):

I have found a way to generate a JSON compilation database from an Xcode project without relying on external tools.

Tools that rely on processing `xcodebuild` output are all deprecated ([oclint-xcodebuild](https://github.com/oclint/oclint-xcodebuild), [xctool](https://github.com/facebookarchive/xctool)) or buggy at best ([xcpretty](https://github.com/xcpretty/xcpretty)), as output format is an implementation detail and subject to change.

The following approach was tested with **Xcode 13.4.1** on macOS 12 Monterey and **Apple Silicon M1 Pro**.

In Xcode Build Settings the following compiler flag can be set:
`OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -gen-cdb-fragment-path $(PROJECT_DIR)/CompilationDatabase`

Alternatively, the flag can be passed when invoking `xcodebuild`:
`xcrun xcodebuid clean build -project TestProject.xcodeproj -target TestTarget -configuration Debug OTHER_CFLAGS="\$(inherited) -gen-cdb-fragment-path \$(PROJECT_DIR)/CompilationDatabase"`

This instructs clang to emit a fragment of the compilation database for each compilation. These fragments can easily be combined into the final compilation database by using the following command:
`sed -e '1s/^/[\'$'\n''/' -e '$s/,$/\'$'\n'']/' *.json > compile_commands.json`

Of course it's recommended to validate fragments, but that cannot be done without external tools.

For full details regarding compiler flags, validation of fragments, and references, check out the gist:
[Generate a JSON Compilation Database from an Xcode project](https://gist.github.com/T1T4N/f4d63a44476eb5c7046cc561cb8c7f77)

Comment: Amazing, thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I got a  proper `compile_commands.json` file (**Xcode 8.3**)

Clean your build

`xcodebuild clean -workspace WORKSPACE.xcworkspace/ -scheme "SCHEME"`

This ensures xcodebuild recompiles all of your files, which would then make them appear in the compilation database.

Build and generate **compile_commands.json**:

`xcodebuild -workspace WORKSPACE.xcworkspace/ -scheme "SCHEME" | xcpretty -r json-compilation-database -o compile_commands.json`

You should obviously replace the workspace and scheme with your projects values. You can also run this against a project by using `-project` instead of `-workspace`.

Answer (score 1):

you try this script

```
#xctool oclint
xctool  -workspace iWeidao.xcworkspace \
        -scheme iWeidao \
        -reporter json-compilation-database:compile_commands.json clean build

oclint-json-compilation-database -v oclint_args "-report-type html -o report.html -rc=LONG_LINE=120"
open compile_commands.json
open report.html
```

here
https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/270

Answer (score 0):

1. try clean the build first, then build again
2. make sure no white space in the file name or path

Answer (score 0):

I just want to combine the answers from earlier ones. There are 2 ways

1. `cd path-to-project-file xcodebuild clean build | xcpretty --report json-compilation-database --output compile_commands.json`
2. `cd path-to-project-file xcodebuild test -project ProjectName.xcodeproj -scheme ProjectTests -destination 'platform=OS X,arch=x86_64' OTHER_CFLAGS="\$(inherited) -gen-cdb-fragment-path \$(PROJECT_DIR)/compilation-database" cd compilation-database sed -e '1s/^/[\'$'\n''/' -e '$s/,$/\'$'\n'']/' *.json > ../compile_commands.json`