# SonarQube build-wrapper silently fails

Tags: sonarqube

I'm running the build-wrapper like so:

```
build-wrapper-macosx-x86 --out-dir build_wrapper_output xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -scheme All -configuration Release clean build
```

However, when I look at the result output the json file is empty:

```
# (C) SonarSource SA, 2014-2022, info@sonarsource.com
# All SONARSOURCE programs and content are copyright protected.
# SONARSOURCE and SONARQUBE are trademarks of SonarSource SA. All rights are expressly reserved.
#
# This file is designed exclusively for use with the SONARSOURCE C / C++ / Objective-C Plugin.
# It may not be used in connection with any other software.
# Any other use is prohibited by law and may be grounds for immediate termination of your License.
{
"version":"6.35",
"captures":[
]}
```

When I run `xcodebuild` normally the build works. Is there something I'm missing here? I tried reading the following and followed the instructions:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/cfamily/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. build wrapper doesnot support Mac os Ventura 13.x

[SonarCommunity, Build wrapper is not working as expected, Objective C, XCode](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/build-wrapper-is-not-working-as-expected-objective-c-xcode/79357/5)

[image: logs]

> Initially, I had used this command: xcodebuild clean build -workspace
> PagaloTodo.xcworkspace -Scheme PagaloTodo and the build is successful.
>
> I had tried passing others configuration options as arch, sdk,
> BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION where also the build is successful
> but the build wrapper generated file is uncomplete.

There is a jira ticket created for same.

Comment: The alternative i found for now is to use the `compilation database`: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/c-family/#using-compilation-database

Answer (score 3):

Starting from macOS 13, wrapper is no longer working, I found below 2 steps  to fix the issue

1. First generate compile commands using `xcpretty` as suggested by sonar
   `xcodebuild clean build | xcpretty --report json-compilation-database --output compile_commands.json`
2. Then use below sonar setting instead of `sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output`
   `sonar.cfamily.compile-commands=compile_commands.json`

If someone is interested what the heck is build wrapper and compilation database, read this page from Sonar https://www.sonarsource.com/blog/alternative-way-to-configure-c-and-cpp-analysis/

Answer (score 1):

Previously we used build wrapper to collect information in a JSON file about Objective-C build configuration during build time.

[Analysis steps using build wrapper](https://docs.sonarqube.org/9.6/analyzing-source-code/languages/c-family/#using-build-wrapper)

Unfortunately, build-wrapper currently doesn’t support macOS 13 Ventura and Apple Silicon.

[[CPP-3987] - Jira](https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/CPP-3987)

Sonar have clearly no plans to keep alive the build wrapper, see:

[build-wrapper macOS: explicitly do not support macOS Ventura 13.x](https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/CPP-4011)

and they closed this support ticket with only a workaround:

https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/CPP-3987

“Use the JSON Compilation Database. To generate a Compilation Database:
if you are using Xcode, use xcpretty”

```
sudo gem install xcpretty
```

Sonar only mentions `xcpretty` in the documentation for Xcode projects so I tried to generate the json dump with `xcpretty` using this command:

```
xcodebuild clean build \
  -workspace TestApp.xcworkspace \
  -scheme TestApp \
  -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='""' CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS='""' \
  CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED='NO' CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED='NO' \
| xcpretty --report json-compilation-database --output xcpretty-compilation-database.json
```

`xcpretty` doesn’t have any other flag which is relevant other than `—report json-compilation-database` and `—output` so there is no room to generate the compilation database in a different way.

Unfortunately Sonar analysis failed to process the resulting json produced by xcpretty:

```
INFO Reached stage: parsing
DEBUG [ParsingError] /Users/balazs630/development/TestApp/Common/Account.m:10 
'Account.h' file not found
```

... and so on. Couldn't find the headers in the project.

Later it turned out that the problem is not with Sonar scanner, but with xcpretty which is buggy.

Luckily I found a poorly documented Xcode compile flag `-gen-cdb-fragment-path` which generates a compilation database json fragment for each Objective-C file.
Then we needed to merge the ~150 fragment that was generated during the clean build into a single .json file to be able to pass it to sonar scanner.

The GitHub Gist page which led to the solution:
https://gist.github.com/T1T4N/f4d63a44476eb5c7046cc561cb8c7f77

from this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73120984/7343596

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the issue and the solution:

**Issue(s):**

- When I updated my OS to macOS 13 and Xcode 15.2 my Sonar Analysis got failed that were already working fine on macOS 12 and Xcode 14.2.

**Solution:**

- Use Compilation Database instead of Build Wrapper

**Details:**

**Old Command (Working fine on on macOS 12 but not on macOS 13):**

```
build-wrapper-macosx-x86/build-wrapper-macosx-x86 \
  --out-dir build_wrapper_output_directory xcodebuild \
  -workspace MyTest.xcworkspace \
  -scheme "MyTest" build \
   CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

**New Command (Working fine on macOS 13):**

```
xcodebuild clean test \
       -workspace MyTest.xcworkspace \
       -scheme "MyTest" \
       -enableCodeCoverage YES \
       CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO \
| xcpretty --report json-compilation-database --output compile_commands.json
```

**The pre-requisite for the new command:** You need to put `gem install xcpretty` in the steps

**Official Documentation Link:**
https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/c-family/

**JIRA Ticket Link:**
https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/CPP-2882